# Is it possible to add a parent selector in LESS?

Tags: css, less

My css is structured in components, each component is stand-alone.

example:

```
.menu {
  background: black;
}
```

The framework I'm using sometimes adds a class to the body-tag. For example for logged in users it would look like this:

```
<body class="loggedIn">
  <div class="menu"</div>
</body
```

I would like to keep the css structured inside each component. Is it possible to add a selector in less that is added before the parent? Something like:

```
.menu{
  %loggedIn{
    color: red
  }
}
```

should give loggedIn users a red menu.

Comment: what is the reason you don't want to use &? There is no parent selector, but the same effect can be achieved using &, like pawel says

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless I am completely missunderstanding you, and there is a possibility, then the ampersand-parent-selector is exactly what you need!

```
.menu{
  .loggedIn & {
    color: red
  }
}
```

Should result in

```
.loggedIn .menu {
  color: red
}
```

Comment: my bad, i thought that would render .menu .loggedIn .menu, but it works!

Answer (score 2):

You can reference the parent selector using `&`: http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature

LESS

```
.menu {
   background: black;
  .loggedIn & {
    color: red
  }
}
```

Will compile to CSS

```
.menu {
   background: black;
}
.loggedIn .menu {
    color: red
}
```

Comment: my bad, i thought that would render .menu .loggedIn .menu, but it works!